# Simulink model inside for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simulink

I want to check how some block parameter affect the results in my simulation.

I use a for loop to change this parameter however it works pretty slow.

```
mdl_name='Gains';
open_system(mdl_name);

for K1 = 1:2
    for K2 = 1:2
        for K3 = 0.1:0.1:2

            set_param([mdl_name,'/Tfn'],'Numerator',mat2str(50),'Denominator',mat2str([20]));
            set_param([mdl_name,'/K1'],'Gain',mat2str(K1));
            set_param([mdl_name,'/K2'],'Gain',mat2str(K2));
            set_param([mdl_name,'/K3'],'Gain',mat2str(K3));

            mdl_name='PWM_Gains';
            open_system(mdl_name);

            Data = sim(mdl_name,'StartTime','40','StopTime','85','FixedStep',num2str(dt));
            Delta_PWM{i} = Data.get('Delta_PWM').signals.values;

            Gains{i} = [K1,K2,K3];

            i = i + 1
        end
    end
end
```

Is there any more efficient way to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parsim`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html).

You can use `load_system` instead of `open_system` to avoid opening simulink. You probably only have to call it once, before the for loop, and not every iteration.

If it still takes too long, try larger stepsize (or variable, to be determined by the ode solver), or a larger step size in the changing parameters.

Example using parsim:

```
% load model
mdl_name='Gains';
load_system(mdl_name);

% parameter to simulate
K1 = 1:2;
K2 = 1:2;
K3 = 0.1:0.1:2;

% create matrix with all combinations
[k1, k2, k3] = ndgrid(K1, K2, K3);
Gains = [k1(:), k2(:), k3(:)];

% Create an array of SimulationInput objects and specify the sweep value for each simulation
numSims = size(Gains,1);
simIn(1:numSims) = Simulink.SimulationInput(model);

% setup models
for idx = 1:numSims
    % get Gains
    K1 = Gains(idx,1);
    K2 = Gains(idx,2);
    K3 = Gains(idx,3);

    % set Gains
    simIn(idx) = simIn(idx).setBlockParameter([mdl_name,'/Tfn'],'Numerator',mat2str(50),'Denominator',mat2str([20]));
    simIn(idx) = simIn(idx).setBlockParameter([mdl_name,'/K1'],'Gain',mat2str(K1));
    simIn(idx) = simIn(idx).setBlockParameter([mdl_name,'/K2'],'Gain',mat2str(K2));
    simIn(idx) = simIn(idx).setBlockParameter([mdl_name,'/K3'],'Gain',mat2str(K3));

    % set simulation parameters
    simIn(idx) = simIn(idx).setModelParameter('StartTime','40', 'StopTime','85','FixedStep',num2str(dt));
end

% Simulate the model 
simOut = parsim(simIn);
```

Comment: How do I use parsim when I need to set multiple blocks (as K1 K2 K3). an example would be appreciated.

Comment: I keep getting thw following error at the blocks where I used mat2str :Error using Simulink.SimulationInput/setBlockParameter
Not enough input arguments.

Comment: Oh sorry, use `num2str`

Comment: Thing is that there is an option that I will need to use mat2str for example simIn(idx).setBlockParameter([mdl_name,'/Tfn'],'Numerator',mat2str([50 20]),'Denominator',mat2str([20 10])); how to make it work then?

Comment: Does normally evaluating mat2str([50 20]) work? Which line do you get the error?